# How can I put a check on controller method 'Create' to avoid the error "Couldn't find Article with 'id'=" in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I put a check on controller method 'Create' to avoid the error "Couldn't find Article with 'id'=" as I want to use create function for both Articles and Posts but here i am commenting from Posts and getting the error, I did try to use if & else like "if params[:post_id] != 0" on both but not working.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize
  def index
  end
  def create
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
      @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
      redirect_to article_path(@article)

      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:username, :comment_body)
  end
end
```

Comment: ``if params[:post_id] != 0`` You should replace it with ``if params[:post_id]``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the parameter is `present?`:

```
def create
  if params[:article_id].present?
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)

  elsif params[:post_id].present?
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to post_path(@post)

  else
    # no parameter at all, redirect or render error page?
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question that is to handle the error `Couldn't find Article with 'id'=` You have to use `find_by` instead of `find` since the latter throws an exception if not found and the former returns nil.

So, the updated code would be

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize
  def index
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.find_by(id: params[:article_id])
    if @article.present?
      @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      # Handle Record not found
    end

    @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:post_id])
    if @post.present?
      @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      # Handle Record not found
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:username, :comment_body)
  end
end
```

Hope this is helpful.